# Why are there HTML5 "<pre>" tags generating in my EJS layout?

Tags: html, express, ejs

I have an annoying issue with an ejs layout (or the browser) generating 'pre' tags around the content within the 'body' without my consent.  I have no idea why it's occurring.  I'm serving up the template with a basic express server.

This is what it looks like:
[Annoying Pre Tag Glitch V2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlRF0.png)

Desired behavior here is obviously to render the content *without* any <'pre'> tags.

Here is my code in 'layout.ejs':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mybrary</title>
</head>
    <body>Why</body>
</html>
```

I've simplified this layout down to its minimal components and the problem is still occurring, which means it can't be due to an ejs variable.

Here's the server code that handles the layouts:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Folder structure is ./views/layouts/layout.ejs although I doubt that has any relevance. I'm using express-ejs-layouts, express, and ejs.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the `body` variable you are passing contains something weird. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've simplified the problematic example down its absolute minimum, you'll see the EJS variable is not the issue.  I've changed the image to include the code on deployment.  I've also added the relevant server code in case that happens to be a contributor.